# What is a 'linkonce' section

Tags: c++, linker

What is a 'linkonce' section, and for extra kudos how does it differ from a comdat section?

To be clear, I'm familiar with how comdat sections work, how they're used, etc.  In googling, *linkonce* is almost exclusively discussed in forums where it's assumed the meaning/intent/purpose of that section is already fairly well understood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc/2003-09/msg00984.html seems to discuss this very thing.

According to that thread, COMDAT is a bit more nebulous in the sense that there's no single correct/standard definition of what constitutes a *true* COMDAT implementation.  g++'s *linkonce* is /an/ implementation of the concept.

In the COMDAT implementations used by MSVC++ and Wind River's 'diab' compiler, their implementations of COMDAT allow it to remove unused sections; eg, if **main.cpp** links against **foo.cpp**, the **main** binary can exclude any COMDAT sections from **foo.o** if the section is not referenced.

I'm uncertain whether this type of folding is applied to the g++ *linkonce* sections, but it seems logical.